# Assign properties to directory Qt, c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to edit a directory to be ReadOnly. I'm using Qt 5.15.2 for the most part of my project, but can't seem to find anything useful other than how to change file permissions. Any ideas on how I could be able to change the directory permissions in a simple way,without having to traverse the files of the directory? :)

Comment: Are you just looking for something like [`QFile::setPermissions`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfile.html#setPermissions)?

Comment: I've used QDir to initialize my directory, and I'm not able to use setPermissions() on it... it only works on QFile, i think.

Comment: Using a `QFile("directory-name")` to set the directory permissions works as expected for me.  If you find otherwise then please [edit] your question to provide more specific details.

Comment: Strange, it won't work for me... Did you create your directory with QDir though? Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: Re. `"Did you create your directory with QDir though?"`: no, I just used an existing directory but I don't think that should matter.  I'm using Qt 5.15.2 on MacOS 10.13.6 in case that's significant.